# How can I add embed images in Google Script

Tags: image, function, discord

I'm trying to add a gif image somewhere along the line here:
 `` let response = `**Check-in Progress :calendar_spiral: ** for <@${myDiscordID}> (${accountName}) !`; ``

Here's the whole code:

```
const profiles = [
  { token: "ltoken=xxxx;", 
    genshin: true, 
    honkai_star_rail: true, 
    honkai_3: false, 
    accountName: "xx" }
];

const discord_notify = true
const myDiscordID = "xxxx"
const discordWebhook = "xxxx"


const urlDict = {
  Genshin_Impact: 'https://sg-hk4e-api.hoyolab.com/event/sol/sign?lang=en-us&act_id=e202102251931481',
  Honkai_Star_Rail: 'https://sg-public-api.hoyolab.com/event/luna/os/sign?lang=en-us&act_id=e202303301540311',
  Honkai_3: 'https://sg-public-api.hoyolab.com/event/mani/sign?lang=en-us&act_id=e202110291205111'
};

async function main() {

  const messages = await Promise.all(profiles.map(autoSignFunction));
  const hoyolabResp = `${messages.join('\n\n')}`;

  if (discord_notify && discordWebhook){
    postWebhook(hoyolabResp);
  }
}


function discordPing() {
  return myDiscordID ? `<@${myDiscordID}> ` : '';
}

function autoSignFunction({ token, genshin, honkai_star_rail, honkai_3, accountName }) {

  const urls = [];

  if (genshin) urls.push(urlDict.Genshin_Impact);
  if (honkai_star_rail) urls.push(urlDict.Honkai_Star_Rail);
  if (honkai_3) urls.push(urlDict.Honkai_3);

  const header = {
    Cookie: token,
    'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'x-rpc-app_version': '2.34.1',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
    'x-rpc-client_type': '4',
    'Referer': 'https://act.hoyolab.com/',
    'Origin': 'https://act.hoyolab.com'
  };

  const options = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: header,
    muteHttpExceptions: true,
  };

 let response = `**Check-in Progress :calendar_spiral: ** for <@${myDiscordID}> (${accountName}) !`;
 

  const httpResponses = UrlFetchApp.fetchAll(urls.map(url => ({ url, ...options })));

  for (const [i, hoyolabResponse] of httpResponses.entries()) {
    const responseJson = JSON.parse(hoyolabResponse)
    const checkInResult = responseJson.message;
    const gameName = Object.keys(urlDict).find(key => urlDict[key] === urls[i])?.replace(/_/g, ' ');
    const isError = checkInResult != "**OK!** :white_check_mark:";
    const bannedCheck = responseJson.data?.gt_result?.is_risk;
    if (bannedCheck) {
      response += `**\n${gameName}**: ${discordPing()} Auto check-in failed due to CAPTCHA blocking.`;
    } else {
      response += `**\n${gameName}**: ${isError ? discordPing() : ""}_${checkInResult}_`;
    }
  };

  return response;
}



function postWebhook(data) {

  let payload = JSON.stringify({
    'username': 'Hoyoverse Check-In',
    'avatar_url': 'https://i.imgur.com/rce83Dn.png',
    'content': data
  });

  const options = {
    method: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    payload: payload,
    muteHttpExceptions: true
  };

  UrlFetchApp.fetch(discordWebhook, options);
}

function runScriptA() {
  ScriptApp.run("1pUkVXPAKuaFkFu82KENTwJsvK2u5IDk3hdUPezzbYVNcPgZ1aenuu9Qb").myFunctionToRun(); // Replace "Script_A_ID" with the actual script ID of Script A
}
```

I did manage to make it display through [Alt Text] (Image URL) but the image was a gif and it's not animating.